# Is it okay to answer with other coding languages/libraries?

Tags: discussion, answers, late-answers, code-languages

I have seen a couple of times questions with just [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) as a language tag getting TypeScript answers, or solutions using other frameworks (like jQuery, lodash, moment.js) that are not mentioned or clearly not used in the question code -- the question author doesn't say it should be answered in vanilla code, nor do they say it's okay if someone suggests using any library.

I sometimes downvote these answers... If it were me I wouldn't have accepted or upvoted them because I would not want to add another dependency to my stack. So I don't think the person who posted the question would want that either.

I also sometimes see a 3-5+ years old question with many answers already where someone sees an opportunity to bump the thread using a TypeScript solution because there where none using TypeScript.

TypeScript is great but, to me, TypeScript and JavaScript are **not** the same, as TypeScript code can't be executed without being transpiled to JavaScript first.

Comment: Do distinguish between a transpiler and a library.  A library is something you can't get rid of, using a transpiler is not different from having to use a text editor first.  Future-proofing the Q+A is not wrong, it was never meant to be static.  Some idea what the future might look like: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=typescript%2Ccoffeescript%2Cdart%2Cactionscript

Comment: You (and Hans) are right about TypeScript: in general, if you use a transpiler, you are writing in a different language. I suspect I would have a torrid time if I began writing PureScript or Haskell answers to [javascript] questions...

Comment: I find these cases difficult to judge. Technically the answers are off-topic, but at the same time I tend to really like it when there are multiple solution paths to a common problem under the same question rather than scattered all over the place. That being said, there is very little need for a TypeScript answer, the conversion from Javascript to Typescript is easy enough that you don't need to just be able to copy/paste solutions.